# Python3 importing files from parent directory / relative importing

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, relative-import

I have the following file structure:

```
parentfolder/
   utils.py
   myProgram/
      main.py
      other.py
```

I will be running the main.py which utilizes other.py which needs to utilize everything in utils.py (NOT just import one method from utils.py at a time - there are global variables and functions that call other functions within this file.)

I have tried lots of different examples online utilizing sys, path, etc. Along with adding `__init__.py` in none, some, and all directories. None of which worked for me.

How do I go about this importing of utils.py within other.py?

If I need to create **init**.py files could you also specify where they need to be created and if anything needs to be placed in them? Do I need to run them once before running the main.py the first time?

Thank you so much for any help in advanced

Comment: What is the current working directory when the program is executed?  This might help as well. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: See my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should add init files as in:

```
parentfolder/
   __init__.py
   utils.py
   myProgram/
      __init__.py
      main.py
      other.py
```

Those can be empty or better containing a docstring on the package contents, but you should not run them or anything

The correct way is to run your script from the parent folder of the parentFolder using the module path:

```
$ cd parentfolder/..
$ python -m parentFolder.myProgram.main
```

This way the `import utils` statement will work without the sys.path hack which can lead to subtle bugs